# How to avoid button with gradient border to jump on hover

Tags: css

I have this button format per snippet below, which I got from a website (i.e. not coded myself). The problem is it bounces on hover. I basically just want the blue border line to be replaced with gradient (without position / size changes on hover).

Could anyone please point out to me what I have to align? Given that I have several buttons, understanding the solution is more important to me than only a fix of this button.

Thank you so much in advance!!

```css
.geodir_submit_search {
color: #000;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-width: 2px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 0px 11px 5px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) !important;
    border-radius: 3px;
    min-height: 0px;
    padding: 7px 10px !important;
    text-align: center;
}
.geodir_submit_search::after {
content: " Search";
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 2px;
font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.showFilters, .showFilters:visited {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) !important;
        color: #000;
        max-width: 40px;
        border: 1px dashed rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}

.showFilters:before, .geodir_submit_search:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  showFilters:before {
    background: #4f4f4f;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
}
.showFilters:hover, .geodir_submit_search:hover {
  border: none !important;
  background:
  linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.4),rgba(255,255,255,0.4)) 2px 2px/calc(100% - 4px) calc(100% - 4px),
  linear-gradient(135deg, #7b63f0, #3ad4c1) 0 0/100% 2px, /* top border */
  linear-gradient(135deg, #7b63f0, #3ad4c1) 0 0/2px 100%, /*left border*/
  linear-gradient(135deg, #3ad4c1, #36b7ee) 0 100%/100% 2px, /* bottom border */
  linear-gradient(135deg, #3ad4c1, #36b7ee) 100% 0/2px 100%; /* right border */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.active {
  background:
  linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,255,255,1) 20%,red) 1px 1px/calc(100% - 2px) calc(100% - 2px) no-repeat, linear-gradient(135deg, #7b63f0, #3ad4c1, #36b7ee);
}

.active:before {
  color: #2084c3;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  .active:before {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #7b63f0 0%, #3ad4c1 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="geodir_submit_search fa">&#xf002;</button>
```

Comment: ah i remember my code ... to bad was too late, or i had answer it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/72ubna0t/), you need to increase padding when hovering, for an amount of the border, which is 2px in your case:

```
.showFilters:hover, .geodir_submit_search:hover {
  border: none !important;
  background:
  linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.4),rgba(255,255,255,0.4)) 2px 2px/calc(100% - 4px) calc(100% - 4px),
  linear-gradient(135deg, #7b63f0, #3ad4c1) 0 0/100% 2px, /* top border */
  linear-gradient(135deg, #7b63f0, #3ad4c1) 0 0/2px 100%, /*left border*/
  linear-gradient(135deg, #3ad4c1, #36b7ee) 0 100%/100% 2px, /* bottom border */
  linear-gradient(135deg, #3ad4c1, #36b7ee) 100% 0/2px 100%; /* right border */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding: 9px 12px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`.showFilters:hover, .geodir_submit_search:hover { border: none !important; }`

with

`.showFilters:hover, .geodir_submit_search:hover { border-color: transparent !important; }`

```css
.geodir_submit_search {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-width: 2px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 0px 11px 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) !important;
  border-radius: 3px;
  min-height: 0px;
  padding: 7px 10px !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.geodir_submit_search::after {
  content: " Search";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.geodir_submit_search:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.geodir_submit_search:hover {
  border-color: transparent !important;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)) 2px 2px/calc(100% - 4px) calc(100% - 4px), linear-gradient(135deg, #7b63f0, #3ad4c1) 0 0/100% 2px, /* top border */
  linear-gradient(135deg, #7b63f0, #3ad4c1) 0 0/2px 100%, /*left border*/
  linear-gradient(135deg, #3ad4c1, #36b7ee) 0 100%/100% 2px, /* bottom border */
  linear-gradient(135deg, #3ad4c1, #36b7ee) 100% 0/2px 100%;
  /* right border */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button class="geodir_submit_search fa">&#xf002;</button>
```

Comment: Hi Connexo, thank you! But in your solution it has a white border outside the gradient border. Unfortunately, this doesnt really work. The gradient border would need to replace the blue border.

Comment: Well, the blue thing is a border, the gradient thing is not. You need to decide which of the two to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea where I use the gradient for the border and the idea is to simply change the colors on hover using CSS variable.

```css
:root {
 --first-color:blue;
 --second-color:blue;
 --third-color:blue;
}

.geodir_submit_search {
  color: #000;
  border:none;
  border-width: 2px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 0px 11px 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)) 2px 2px/calc(100% - 4px) calc(100% - 4px), 
  linear-gradient(135deg, var(--first-color), var(--second-color)) 0 0/100% 2px, /* top border */
  linear-gradient(135deg, var(--first-color), var(--second-color)) 0 0/2px 100%, /*left border*/
  linear-gradient(135deg, var(--second-color), var(--third-color)) 0 100%/100% 2px, /* bottom border */
  linear-gradient(135deg, var(--second-color), var(--third-color)) 100% 0/2px 100%;
  /* right border */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 3px;
  min-height: 0px;
  padding: 9px 12px !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.geodir_submit_search::after {
  content: " Search";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.geodir_submit_search:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.geodir_submit_search:hover {
    --first-color:#7b63f0;
 --second-color:#3ad4c1;
 --third-color:#36b7ee;
 
}
```

```html
<button class="geodir_submit_search fa">&#xf002;</button>
```